# HAVING clause with subquery -- Checking if group has at least one row matching conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, count

Suppose I have the following table

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #toy_example
CREATE TABLE #toy_example
(
    Id int,
    Pet varchar(10)
);
INSERT INTO #toy
VALUES (1, 'dog'),
(1, 'cat'),
(1, 'emu'),
(2, 'cat'),
(2, 'turtle'),
(2, 'lizard'),
(3, 'dog'),
(4, 'elephant'),
(5, 'cat'),
(5, 'emu')
```

and I want to fetch all Ids that have certain pets (for example either cat or emu, so Ids 1, 2 and 5).

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Pets
CREATE TABLE #Pets
(
    Animal varchar(10)
);
INSERT INTO #Pets
VALUES ('cat'),
('emu')

SELECT Id
FROM #toy_example
GROUP BY Id
HAVING COUNT(
    CASE
       WHEN Pet IN (SELECT Animal FROM #Pets) 
       THEN 1 
    END
) > 0
```

The above gives me the error `Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.` I have two questions:

1. Why is this an error? If I instead hard code the subquery in the HAVING clause, i.e. `WHEN Pet IN ('cat','emu')` then this works. Is there a reason why SQL server (I've checked with SQL server 2017 and 2008) does not allow this?
2. What would be a nice way to do this? Note that the above is just a toy example. The real problem has many possible "Pets", which I do not want to hard code. It would be nice if the suggested method could check for multiple other similar conditions too in a single query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I followed you correctly, you can just `join` and aggregate:

```
select t.id, count(*) nb_of_matches
from #toy_example t
inner join #pets p on p.animal = t.pet 
group by t.id
```

The `inner join` eliminates records from `#toy_example` that have no match in `#pets`. Then, we aggregate by `id` and count how many recors remain in each group.

If you want to retain records that have no match in `#pets` and display them with a count of `0`, then you can `left join` instead:

```
select t.id, count(*) nb_of_records, count(p.animal) nb_of_matches
from #toy_example t
left join #pets p on p.animal = t.pet 
group by t.id
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this approach?

```
SELECT e.Id
FROM #toy_example e JOIN
     #pets p
     ON e.pet = p.animal
GROUP BY e.Id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT e.pet) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #pets);
```

Comment: Sorry, I've clarified my question -- I'm after Ids that have any pet from #pets. It would be nice to also be able to control the number of matches too.

Comment: @Presquevu . . . Just remove the `having` clause then.